Python positioning widgets on a grid
Sory for my poor english i'm speeking french.
I'm starting dev on python and i try to use Tkinter for programming my GUI then, i've some troubles with the alignement of some colums in my python app which is divide on 3 colums.
root = tk.Tk()
root.title('My first App')
root.option_add("*tearOff", False)

root.columnconfigure(index=0, weight=1)
root.columnconfigure(index=1, weight=1)
root.columnconfigure(index=2, weight=1)
root.rowconfigure(index=0, weight=1)
root.rowconfigure(index=1, weight=1)
root.rowconfigure(index=2, weight=1)

frame = ttk.Frame(root)
frame.pack()

# 1st column
widgets_frame = ttk.LabelFrame(frame, text="Informations")
widgets_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew', rowspan=3)

# 2nd column
prof_frame = ttk.LabelFrame(frame, text="Situation")
prof_frame.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='nsew', columnspan=2, rowspan=3)

# 3rd column
studies_frame = ttk.LabelFrame(frame, text="Diplômes")
studies_frame.grid(row=0, column=4, sticky='nsew')

For the 1st column, there's no problems.
But for the 2nd, I divide it on 2 lines:
1st Line has been divided in 2 columns

col1: professionnal situation,
col2: may contains a picture of the user at the first line and the blood infos on the second line.

Here is the first problem when i put the rows for blood information everything goes wrong.
2nd line there's no pb.
And finaly the informations of my last column are not where they may be but into the second bloc.
Here's my code
**# 2nd column row 1

prof_frame = ttk.LabelFrame(frame, text="Situation")
prof_frame.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='nsew', columnspan=2, rowspan=3)

statuts_frame = ttk.LabelFrame(prof_frame, text="Statut", padding=(20, 10))
statuts_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew', columnspan=2, rowspan=6, padx=(20, 10), pady=(20, 10))

check_1 = ttk.Checkbutton(statuts_frame, text="Stagiaire", variable=c)
check_1.state(["alternate"])
check_1.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=5, pady=10, sticky="nsew")

check_2 = ttk.Checkbutton(statuts_frame, text="Intégré", variable=c)
check_2.state(["alternate"])
check_2.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=5, pady=10, sticky="nsew")

check_2 = ttk.Checkbutton(statuts_frame, text="MONP", variable=c)
check_2.state(["alternate"])
check_2.grid(row=3, column=0, padx=5, pady=10, sticky="nsew")

check_3 = ttk.Checkbutton(statuts_frame, text="Retraité", variable=c)
check_3.state(["alternate"])
check_3.grid(row=4, column=0, padx=5, pady=10, sticky="nsew")

check_4 = ttk.Checkbutton(statuts_frame, text="Décédé", variable=c)
check_4.state(["alternate"])
check_4.grid(row=5, column=0, padx=5, pady=10, sticky="nsew")

photo_frame = ttk.LabelFrame(prof_frame, text="Photo", padding=(10, 10))
photo_frame.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='nsew', columnspan=2, rowspan=3, padx=(20, 10), pady=(20, 10))

photo_image = PhotoImage(file='./assets/icons/upload_image.png')
up_photo_btn = ttk.Button(photo_frame, text='Photo', image=photo_image, compound=CENTER)
up_photo_btn.grid(row=0, column=0)

sang_frame = ttk.LabelFrame(photo_frame, text="Sang", padding=(5,5))
sang_frame.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky='nsew', columnspan=2, rowspan=3)**

# I want to align it verticaly but it look like difficult

radio_1 = ttk.Radiobutton(sang_frame, text="A", variable=d, value=1)
radio_1.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5, pady=10, sticky="nsew")
radio_2 = ttk.Radiobutton(sang_frame, text="A-B", variable=d, value=2)
radio_2.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=5, pady=10, sticky="nsew")
radio_3 = ttk.Radiobutton(sang_frame, text="B", variable=d, value=1)
radio_3.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=5, pady=10, sticky="nsew")
radio_4 = ttk.Radiobutton(sang_frame, text="O", variable=d, value=2)
radio_4.grid(row=3, column=0, padx=5, pady=10, sticky="nsew")

the code of the last column
parcours_frame = ttk.LabelFrame(frame, text="Diplômes")
parcours_frame.grid(row=0, column=4, sticky='nsew')

dip_civiles = ttk.LabelFrame(parcours_frame, text="Statut", padding=(20, 10))
statuts_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew', columnspan=2, rowspan=6, padx=(20, 10), pady=(20, 10))

check_cep = ttk.Checkbutton(statuts_frame, text="CEP", variable=c)
check_cep.state(["alternate"])
check_cep.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5, pady=10, sticky="nsew")

check_bepc = ttk.Checkbutton(statuts_frame, text="BEPC", variable=c)
check_bepc.state(["alternate"])
check_bepc.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=5, pady=10, sticky="nsew")

check_bac = ttk.Checkbutton(statuts_frame, text="BAC", variable=c)
check_bac.state(["alternate"])
check_bac.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=5, pady=10, sticky="nsew")

check_lic = ttk.Checkbutton(statuts_frame, text="Licence", variable=c)
check_lic.state(["alternate"])
check_lic.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=5, pady=10, sticky="nsew")

check_mast = ttk.Checkbutton(statuts_frame, text="Master", variable=c)
check_mast.state(["alternate"])
check_mast.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=5, pady=10, sticky="nsew")

check_doc = ttk.Checkbutton(statuts_frame, text="Doctorat", variable=c)
check_doc.state(["alternate"])
check_doc.grid(row=1, column=2, padx=5, pady=10, sticky="nsew")

My output
1- Col2.row1.col1
2- Col2.row1.col2
3- Col3.row0.col0

Try deleting the rowspan and columnspan options in grid for the frames.  ( take a copy first in case it makes it worse) The grid manager will organise your widgets within the frame based on the grid row and column options.  As it is, for example, the photo_frame is hiding the last two columns of the statutes_frame.  Does that make things clearer?
